# Firebase results range using startAt and endAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the first 100 results from my Firebase data, then the next 100, then the next 100 etc. I've tried multiple ways.

Version 1

```
ref.child('products').orderByChild('domain').startAt(0).endAt(100).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {});
```

Version 2

```
ref.child('products').orderByChild('domain').startAt(0).limitToFirst(100).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {});
```

Version 3

```
ref.child('products').startAt(0).endAt(100).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {});
```

Every time the snapshot returned is null. Is there anyway in Firebase of getting the range of data I'm after?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `orderByChild()` any subsequent call to `startAt()`, `endAt()` or `equalTo()` expects the value that you pass in to be a child. You're passing in an index. Unless the value of `domain` is a sequential index (highly unlikely), this will not work.

What you should do is remember the `domain` value of the last child you got, and then pass that in to `startAt()` for the next "page".

```
var productsRef = ref.child('products');
var lastKnownDomainValue = null;
var pageQuery = productsRef.orderByChild('domain').limitToFirst(100);
pageQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
    lastKnownDomainValue = childSnapshot.child('domain').val();
  });
});
```

Now you have a variable `lastKnownDomainValue` that has the last domain you've ever seen. To get the next batch of children, you pass that value in to `startAt()`:

```
var nextQuery = productsRef.orderByChild('domain').startAt(lastKnownDomainValue).limitToFirst(100);
```

And then you update `lastKnownDomainValue` when you loop over the children again.

Comment: Couldn't you collapse `pageQuery` and `nextQuery` into a single function that could accept any range?

Comment: @frank-van-puffelen Are you saying Firebase doesn't support range queries where you have a start value (say a date) and and end value? and if so, does Firestore also have that limitation?

Comment: @Aodh Range queries with a start and end value are possible on both. If you're having trouble, post a question with the minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck.