# Implementing Infinite Scrolling with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
      var self = this;
      var firebaseRef = new Firebase(baseUrl + '/sparks');

      firebaseRef.limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
        self.addChild(childSnapshot); // adds post to a <div>
      });
```

[image: database layout]

My code currently loads the last 5 posts and will load any new posts. However, I'd also like to be able to load older posts as well. I have a button that when clicked will call a function (that I'm unsure of how to implement) that loads older posts. **How do I retrieve these older posts?**

(The arrow just signifies that I want to retrieve posts starting from the bottom and working my way up to the top)

Comment: What is `__firebaseKey__`? Can you set up a repro on a site like jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I updated my post. Hope it's more clear what my objective is

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to think a bit backwards to do this. When you get the results for your query for the first page, remember the first item in the results:

```
firebaseRef.endAt().limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
    self.addChild(childSnapshot); // adds post to a <div>
  });
```

While you cannot access child items by index with Firebase, you can store the key of an item and use that to start a next query.

```
var firstKnownKey;
firebaseRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
    if (!firstKnownKey) {
      firstKnownKey = childSnapshot.key;
    }
    self.addChild(childSnapshot); // adds post to a <div>
});
```

Now you have a variable firstKnownKey that has the first key you've ever seen. To get the previous batch of children, you pass that value in to `endAt()` when you fire your next query:

```
firebaseRef.orderByKey().endAt(firstKnownKey).limitToLast(5).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
    if (!firstKnownKey) {
      firstKnownKey = childSnapshot.key;
    }
    self.addChild(childSnapshot); // adds post to a <div>
});
```

Answers to similar questions of the past few days:

- [Can I get the nth item of a firebase "query"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079061/can-i-get-the-nth-item-of-a-firebase-query/35086931#35086931)
- [Firebase results range using startAt and endAt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025419/firebase-results-range-using-startat-and-endat/35026817#35026817)

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed. My issues were not using orderByKey(), using startAt instead of EndAt and limitToFirst instead of limitToLast!

Comment: @Frank, your third piece of code will return every time the same result, because the `firstKnownKey` will be the same as when we getting the first batch.

Comment: You will have to update `firstKnownKey` for each page that you load.

Comment: I have spent more than 8 hours getting this working. Can you, please give to us an more detailed example for this?
I have this: https://i.imgur.com/7WTWxYu.png
Getting first batch working fine, but after that I will receive duplicate sets of results and I don't know how to fix that.
Thanks!

Comment: @FinPercy Please use `<!---->` to get around the 6 character limit when editing.

Answer (score 1):

Since `endAt()` is inclusive, the last item gets repeated every time I do the infinite scroll, so I did a little modification to [frank van puffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) 's answer.

I initiate a list `childrenVal` to store all the values, another list `childrenKey` to store all the keys and a var `firstKnownKey`, as [frank van puffen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen) sugests.

```
var childrenVal=[];
var childrenKey=[];
var firstKnownKey = "";
```

For the first time you make the query, you get the last 5 elements:

```
getFirst(){
    firebaseRef.orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value')
        .then((snap)=>{
            snap.forEach(childSnap => {
                childrenVal.unshift(childSnap.val());
                childrenKey.unshift(childSnap.key);
            });
            firstKnownKey = childrenKey[childrenKey.length-1];
        });
}
```

In your next query, you won't want your `firstKnownKey` to get repeated, so I did the following function:

```
exclude(key){
    return key.substring(0, key.length - 1) + String.fromCharCode(key.charCodeAt(key.length - 1) - 1)
}
```

and for the query itself, the following function:

```
getNext() {
    firebaseRef.orderByKey().endAt(exclude(firstKnownKey)).limitToLast(5).once('value')
        .then((snap) => {
            snap.forEach(childSnap => {
                childrenVal.unshift(childSnap.val());
                childrenKey.unshift(childSnap.key);
            });
            firstKnownKey = childrenKey[childrenKey.length - 1];
        });
}
```