# Fetching data using limitoLast returns null using endAt()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I wanted to implement infinite scroll to load more data in my app. I wanted to fetch the data from latest to oldest i.e from bottom to top , so I have used `limiToLast()`

I have followed [Implementing Infinite Scrolling with Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098894/implementing-infinite-scrolling-with-firebase#) to achieve this functionality.

Here is my query function

```
var lastKey = '';
var myData = [];

async fetchData(){
    try{
        var snap = await firebase.database().ref(category).orderByKey().endAt(lastKey).limitToLast(5).once('value');
        console.log(snap);
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {
            myData.push(childSnap.val();
            lastKey = childSnap.key;
        });
    }catch(err){
        //handle errors
    }
}
```

But the `snap` is null if I console.log it.
what am I doing wrong?
**I want to fetch 5 items at a time from the bottom**
if I use the same code using `startAt()` and `limitToFirst()` to fetch 5 items at a time it works fine:

```
var lastKey = '';
var myData = [];

async fetchData(){
    try{
        var snap = await firebase.database().ref(category).orderByKey().startAt(lastKey).limitToFirst(5).once('value');
        snap.forEach(childSnap => {
            myData.push(childSnap.val();
            lastKey = childSnap.key;
        });
    }catch(err){
        //handle errors
    }
}
```

Comment: your lastKey is empty when you do endAt, so i think it will stop even before even hitting the first node.

Comment: startAt works by starting the search from an empty string, so it will start from the first element

Comment: Please edit your question to include the `console.log()` statement, since the behavior depends on *where* you log.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the console.log statement