# Firebase database get data of child with limit and start/end at

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
post:{
  pushKey1:{
    text:1,
    user:user1
  },
  pushKey2:{
    text:2,
    user:user1
  },
  pushKey3:{
    text:3,
    user:user2
  },
  pushKey4:{
    text:4,
    user:user1
  },
  pushKey5:{
    text:5,
    user:user3
  },
  pushKey6:{
    text:6,
    user:user1
  },
  pushKey7:{
    text:7,
    user:user1
  }
}
```

i want data where user = user1 and get 2 data at a time using limit 2 and start/end at previous received pushKey so i can use pagination

query should be look like this

```
ref().child("post").orderByChild("user").equalTo("user1").endAt(pushKey4).limitToFirst(2).get();
```

I expect data the first time i should get `pushKey7`,`pushKey6`, and after second call `pushkey4` and `pushkey2`, and third time call should come `pushKey1` (pushKey3,pushKey5 should not come because user does not match).

Comment: please edit the question as it is hard to guess the exact need? also i think you mixed-up here so should look in to documentation 1st. also see [firebase-results-range-using-startat-and-endat#35026817](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35025419/firebase-results-range-using-startat-and-endat#35026817)

Comment: You've written `pushKey4` in the code as a variable. Did you mean for that to be a (hard-coded) string? If so, please fix the code sample (there's an `edit` link under your question that allows you to do so). If not, please edit your question to show how `pushKey4` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call any of the `orderBy...` operation on the API, all filtering operations (`startAt`, `endAt`, `equalTo`, etc) work on the values that you've ordered on. So both your `equalTo` and `endAt` operations work on the `user` values, so the `endAt` operation doesn't do what you expect it to be.

If you want to get all child nodes where the `user` property is `"user1"`, but end at the one where the ID/key of the node is `"pushKey4"`, you can pass that key as the second argument to any of the filtering API calls. You'll need to use `startAt` and `endAt` in this case, as otherwise only one node would ever match - while you seem to want a slice of the results.

So in your example:

```
ref().child("post")
     .orderByChild("user")
     .startAt("user1")
     .endAt("user1", "pushKey4")
```

Now the database will return the nodes where the `user` property is `user1`, starting at the first one and ending at the one with ID/key `"pushKey4"`.